# Animating the Colormesh plot in python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here I have made a simple program, which populate a 2-D mesh by taking values from a matrix(NxN) 'config' which has random values from (-1 to 1).
I want this plot to be animated so that when I update these values in Matrix the plots gets updated.
I have seen few animation codes ,but the are not what I am looking.
Can someone point me to right direction.
Thank You.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

f = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), dpi=80);
N=10
n_=1
i=1

config = 2*np.random.uniform(2, size=(N,N))-3
print(config)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(N), range(N))
#print(X)

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, config, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu);
plt.title('Time=%d' % i);
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

We can make a new matrix/tensor "animate_grid" with (TxNxN), i.e. NxN matrix of updated value(any values even random) for each time step T.
   example

```
 T=0 
[[-0.244608 -0.71395497 -0.36534627]  
[-0.44626849 -0.82385746 -0.74654582]
[ 0.38240205 -0.58970239  0.67858516]]
T=1
[[-0.46084 -0.3413957 -0.3453345627]
[-0.43626849 -0.6385746 -0.4654582]
[ 0.8240205 -0.8970239  0.37858516]]
T=2 
[[-0.4546084 -0.9565497 -0.534627]
[-0.2546849 -0.8345746 -0.465654582]
[ 0.4460205 -0.4660239  0.6858516]]
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail which other answers have not helped you and in how far they did not? Could you also explain more in detail what you expect your code to produce? How would you change the matrix? Please do so by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: We can make a new matrix/tensor "animate_grid" with (TxNxN), i.e. NxN matrix of updated value(any values even random) for each time step T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation would work just as in any other case. You need a function that updates the plot and an instance of `FuncAnimation` which calls this updating function regularly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
N=10
T=17
config = np.random.rand(T, N,N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(N+1), range(N+1))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=80)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, config[0,:,:], cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
plt.title('Time=%d' % 0)

def update(i):
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, config[i,:,:], cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
    plt.title('Time=%d' % i)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=config.shape[0], 
                              interval = 100, repeat = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.